# Windows change size on mac after reopening from dock

Tags: big-sur, dock, window-manager

I believe this started happening after the update to Big Sur (currently on 11.2.3).

I'm using a Mac book pro with an external monitor as a second display (not mirrored).

The annoying issue is that when I hide a window by clicking the yellow circle, and later click on the window from the dock to reshow the window, the size and position of the window is different than before.  It is super annoying because I then need to manually put the window back where it was before.

This won't happen if I hide the window and immediately reopen it.  I suspect it only happens if I hide the window, the mac goes to sleep, and I then reshow the window.

Is there a fix for this?  I find it super annoying to have fix my window size/position all the time.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but I'd suggest there's very little need to hide individual windows ever. MacOS provides plenty of ways to navigate between windows: there's Application Windows, Mission Control, plus Command `. And right-clicking on the Dock icon. You can hide the whole application (or all the others) with Command H, and that's before Spaces/Desktops and Full Screen views. Since OS X was first released, I've never intentionally hidden a window, and I'll race anyone's workflow with mine!

Comment: The OS isn't doing it, so no, there's not a "fix", other than removing whatever other window "manager" you have installed.  Also, you're not hiding windows when you use that control, you're minimizing them.

Comment: Hi @MarcWilson, I haven't installed any window manager.  This is just regular Finder and macOS.

Comment: By "size and position of the window is different " do you mean it moves from the external screen to the internal, or that it is on the correct screen, but re-sized?